# Using PURL on Cloud Pages not working

Tags: marketing-cloud, custom-url, cloudpage

I'm trying to figure out how to pass a coupon value to a Cloud Page from an email deployed via SFMC.  I'm definitely a neophyte when it comes to this stuff, but this can't be that hard?!?!

After reading the online documentation I figured I would use a combination of a PURL and AMPscript as I'm comfortable with AMPscript

For whatever reason I can't get the coupon code to display.  I've tried the following in the cloud page:

```
%%[ SET @couponID = LookUp("Coupons","CouponCode","EmailAddress",emailaddr) ]%%
    %%=v(@couponID)=%%
```

and in the email, I have the cloud page URL with the appropriate URL string:

```
?emailaddress=%%emailaddr%%
```

The Coupon Code is definitely populating into the email, I just can't get it to display on the Cloud Landing Page.  I know there's a SSJS way to do this, but I don't know SSJS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your major issue is that the emailaddr is blank, so your lookup will fail. I would not recommend using the string emailaddr is outside of email creatives.

You are using a parameter to pass the value, so you would need to [request this parameter](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/requestparameter.htm) and then set the variable in your lookup.

See below:

```
 %%=[  
      SET @EmailAddress = RequestParameter("emailaddress")
      SET @coupoonID = LookUp("Coupons", "CouponCode", "EmailAddress", @EmailAddress)
  ]%%
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed.  Thank you.  It's always a simple oversight, isn't it?

Comment: Glad to have helped! If you feel this has solved your issue, please feel free to click the check mark next to this answer to mark it as accepted.